# Why is my Python script is not dealing with indexes properly when I am trying to reformat the data

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
cleaned_df = pd.read_csv('filepath/test.csv',
                    index_col=1, parse_dates=True)

id_list = list(set(cleaned_df.loc[:, 'id'].tolist()))

df_list = []  # Create an empty list to store individual dataframes

for id in id_list:
    id_df = cleaned_df[cleaned_df['id'] == id].loc[:, ['exportEnergykWh', 'importEnergykWh']]
    id_df.rename(columns={'exportEnergykWh': id + '_export', 'importEnergykWh': id + '_import'}, inplace=True)
    df_list.append(id_df)  # Append each dataframe to the list

changed_df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0)
```

I am using the above code to take something in the format

```
timestamp, exportEnergykWh, importEnergykWh, id
2023-10-04 06:00, 0, 1.3, s14j575
2023-10-04 06:00, 1.2, 3.1, f91734
2023-10-04 06:00, 0.4, 2.1, t91u10
2023-10-04 06:30, 0, 1.4, s14j575
2023-10-04 06:30, 1.1, 2.1, f91734
2023-10-04 06:30, 0.3, 1.7, t91u10
```

into something that has many more columns

```
timestamp, s14j575_export, s14j575_import, f91734_export, f91734_import, t91u10_export, t91u10_import
2023-10-04 06:00, 0, 1.3, 1.2, 3.1, 0.4, 2.1,
2023-10-04 06:30, 0, 1.4, 1.1, 2.1, 0.3, 1.7,
```

it should much fewer rows, but there is something wrong with how I am dealing with the indexes, so I get a repeated index with the same value and the columns have NaN values in most rows, rather than a few rows all with data. It has been a while since I have used Pandas, would appreciate any help

Comment: You're creating one `df_list` entry for every element in `id_list`.  Why do you think you'll get fewer rows?

Comment: I'd suggest you provide some sample data and instead of just saying you want to reformat the data, say *how* you want to reformat the data. Offhand, it looks like to me you want to concat column-wise instead of row-wise but not really sure.

Comment: is your id variable same? if not, you cannot concat dataframes with different column names.

Comment: Can you include a modest CSV file so the problem can be demonstrated and answers can be tested?

Comment: Okay, so you have a csv with _timestamp, exportEnergykWh, importEnergykWh, id_. So why drop non-existent _['inverterId', 'hour']_? You want an output csv with many more columns, but _timestamp, id_export, id_import_ is fewer columns. If you gave us sample input and desired output, there would be less guessing.

Comment: @tdelaney I have added some data in the format it is when it is added, and what I want

Comment: @yash I have added some examples of the data, there are multiple ids for the data imported

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

`changed_df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)`

possibly this:
`changed_df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1, ignore_index=True)`

It might be also possible to get the same result with `pivot`.

also a couple of points to improve your code if I may:

- it's better to not use `id` as a variable name
- instead of `df.loc[:, columns]` you can simply use `df[columns]`